Adding a point on the LS line to the training set
A naive statistical question:
Suppose I have a training set and I calculate a plain old OLS regression model.
Now I generate a point -on- that predicted linear surface, that is, this new point has 0 loss (or 0 MSE).
Does the training set augmented with this new point have a different model or the same model?
On the one hand, it seems like it should be no different because a zero loss would lead to that instance contributing no change to the model. (if the original set only has d+1 points then the solution model passes through all those points and an additional one on the surface would make no difference).
On the other hand, the original set plus new point may well have a (very slightly) different model...I don't see how the closed form solution $\beta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$ could possibly be the same with any kind of new point.

I don't think a new point that matches the model is guaranteed to not change the model for any process, eg k Nearest Neighbors. Right?

Part of the motivation for this question, and why I think it is naive, is that in a logic system, if you have a theorem implied by the axioms, and you add a consequence of the theorem as an axiom itself, you still get the exact same set of of theorems. That a statistical model has the same properties is not guaranteed but is intuitively analogous.

Let's translate the question into simpler terms.  Doing so leads instantly to the answer (and it's consistent with your intuition).
"Plain old OLS" means that given a design matrix $X$ and response vector $y,$ you found some vector of parameters $\hat\beta$ that minimizes the sum of squares of residuals $||y - X\hat\beta||^2.$
"Generate a point on" means you select some row vector $x_0$ and number $y_0$ for which $x_0\hat\beta = y.$
The question is whether $\hat\beta$ still minimizes the new sum of squared residuals, equal to
$$||y - X\hat\beta||^2 + (y_0 - x_0\hat\beta)^2.$$
Because $\hat\beta$ solves the original OLS problem, the first term cannot become any smaller using an alternative value of $\hat\beta.$  The second term, being the square of a quantity, cannot be any less than $0,$ which it is by construction.  Consequently the answer is yes: $\hat\beta$ is an OLS solution for the augmented problem, QED.

A subtlety is that $\hat\beta$ needn't be unique.  As an example, suppose the original problem is given by
$$X = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1};\quad y = \pmatrix{0\\2}.$$
There are multiple solutions minimizing the objective function
$$||y - X\beta||^2 = (0 - (\beta_1+\beta_2))^2 + (2 - (\beta_1+\beta_2))^2 = 4 - 4(\beta_1+\beta_2) + 2(\beta_1+\beta_2)^2,$$
all of the form
$$\hat\beta(t) = \pmatrix{\hat\beta_1\\\hat\beta_2} = \pmatrix{t\\1-t}$$
for any real number $t.$
We might take, for instance, $\hat\beta=\hat\beta(0) = (0,1)^\prime.$
To illustrate the question, adjoin the data $x_0 = (1, 1),$ $y_0 = x_0\hat\beta = 1.$  As we have seen, the new OLS problem is solved by $\hat\beta = (0,1)^\prime,$ but it is also solved by any of the other $\hat\beta(t),$ as you can readily check.
If we take the more sophisticated perspective that "the" solution to an OLS problem is an affine subspace $B$ where all $\hat\beta\in B$ minimize the least squares objective; and if we generalize the question to "what happens to the solution when a collection of points on the solution set are adjoined to the data," then -- using an identical analysis -- the answer is "$B$ remains unchanged."
What will change is the estimated variance-covariance matrix of the parameter estimates and everything that flows from that, including standard errors of parameter estimates, p-values, and confidence limits.  They will all seem to improve because we have created the appearance of more data leading to the same solution.

I found that the answer by @ThomasLumley already dealt with making it plausible that OLS with an added point that has zero cost doesn't change the estimate. The OP also states that from one point of view this is clear with „On the one hand, it seems like it should be no different because...“. I thought that the question is more specifically about „I don't see how the closed form solution $\beta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$ could possibly be the same with any kind of new point.“

@Sextus (1) Lumley deleted that post.  (2) I have explicitly approached the question in a roundabout way: because the Normal equations are derived from the OLS criterion, seeing that the original solution works with a point adjoined perforce demonstrates the augmented Normal equations are satisfied, without having to do any of the linear algebra (and without having to cope with the problem of reduced-rank $X$). Quite a conceptual and mathematical savings, don't you think? ;-)

"without having to do any of the linear algebra" I had the idea that the question was about doing that algebra without the roundabout way.

I do like the subtlety +1, but it seems to touch on a different topic then the OP intended.

@Sextus I understand and appreciate that.  My reaction, though, is that if the intention was to formulate a purely algebraic solution, then the question belongs on the Math site rather than here.  I think it's fair to presume that questions posted here wish to focus on the statistical aspects rather than the purely mathematical ones.

My own idea was to first to tackle the answer head on, and my deleted post shows that this doesn't bring much intuition. Then the second idea was to use something along the lines of Intuition behind $(X^TX)^{-1}$ in closed form of w in Linear Regression. I currently have only some ideas in $n=3$ points, and I am not sure they hold in general, but I am currently imagining starting with $n+1$ points and assuming one of them with zero residual and making it zero. That is making a data point zero and the opposite from adding a data point.

@SextusEmpiricus Re: "I thought that the question is more specifically about..." - I had two contradictory intuitions so an explanation for the right intuition is what it was about.

@whuber re $$||y - X\hat{\beta}||^2 + (y_0 - x_0\hat{\beta})^2.$$ not to be skeptical... but I'm going to be skeptical... Is that really the new MSE? If so, woohoo, yes that super simplifies all the crazy algebra I imagined because, by design, $(y_0 - x_0\hat{\beta})^2 = 0$ so adding $(x_0,y_0)$ to the set doesn't change $\hat{\beta}$.

Also wtf with SE and latex and \hat.

Since there is a general vague 'humanities' (?) intuition that if you add an instance to a training set for a pattern finder that matches the pattern finder already, then it doesn't change the pattern. But there's no guarantee except by math. And I was just checking the math for OLS and it seemed daunting to manipulate a bunch of matrices with an extra row.

Also, surely this would be quickly confirmed by a short python experiment but I'm lazy I thought others might like to know.

Mitch, yes that's the new MSE because it uses all the data--old and new--and computes the MSE with respect to the old parameter estimate.  The question comes down to whether you can find any other parameter estimate that strictly decreases the MSE.  You can't, because you can't decrease the first term and the second term is already zero.  And you've put your finger on it: it obviates any need for the crazy algebra and shows directly and clearly why the estimate does not change.

BTW, the "pattern finder" characterization might be too broad, but the same argument should apply to minimizing any loss function that sums over the data.  (Many ML techniques are not that simple, so beware generalizations!)

@whuber yes, generalization to other ML methods was my next question, thanks for anticipating.
